# Isn't the @Column annotation enough for JPA to map a cammel case Java property to a snake case column on the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Iam sending this json from the frontend to save a resource on the API:

```
 {"senha":"232323","sexo":"masculino","primeiroNome":"Robert","sobrenome":"Afonso","creci":"160j","email":"robert@bol.com.br"}
```

All the values are saved, except primeiroNome.

in my database I have column names: senha, sexo, sobrenome and "primeiro_nome". As you can see, primeiro_nome is the only composed column name.

I have the following annotation:

```
  @Column(name="primeiro_nome")
   private String primeiroNome;
```

But it seems not to be enough. What can I do?

Comment: Wait a minute it seems there's something wrong in my code.  The gettters and setters aren't right!

Answer (score 0):

It's was the getters and setters. One mistake led to another. I had named my property primero_nome(missing "i"). After correcting the property I didn't corrected the setters and getters. It was like the property didn't have getters and setters. Because primeiro_nome  was the only "different" column  I was looking in the wrong direction.